# Some website pages not indexed by Google although followed the recommended steps

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-index, xml-sitemap

I have built a website (www.shareall.nl) in wordpress and did some SEO (metadescriptions, headings, links, alt text, microdata, sitemap, robots.txt, etc) using Yoast Wordpress SEO plugin. I did not squeezed everything out of it but the site ranks pretty well in Google on important keywords regarding Prezi (top 5).

The problem however is, that there is a set of pages that are not being indexed and these pages are relevant to my customer? One of the pages is http://www.shareall.nl/prezi-trainingen/prezi-vervolgtraining (I cannot post more links due to my reputation on stackoverflow, but they are all about training).

I know (as the moderator told me) that there is another question about this topic but I have followed all recommendations given there without success. I would like to get more ideas of what to try and hope someone can help me with this.

This is what I have done so far or are some facts about the site which might be relevant:

submitted sitemap and saw most of the pages being indexed

robot.txt is not preventing pages from being crawled

manually crawled pages using google's webmaster tools and submitted them afterwards

the website itself has multiple links from other pages towards the training pages

don't have noindex set for concerned pages

domain is not new and exists for numerous years now (since 2011)

the website **is** new and is launched this year (february 2014)

I have multiple links within the site pointing to the missing pages

Again any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a sitemap does not guarantee that all of the pages get crawled - Google does not look at everything.

Use the [Fetch as Google tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) to fetch and then index the missing pages.